# Recovering from a sous vide disaster

Tags: food-safety, chicken, sous-vide

I batch cooked 4 large boneless chicken breasts last night for 90 minutes at what I thought was 63c but actually turned out to be 60c. When cutting up the chicken to add to the sauce it was clear that the chicken was not fully cooked and some parts looked raw and pink in colour with a different texture.

I decided to cook the chicken further in the sauce but this (quite understandably) ended up with classic "Rubber chicken".

Having two pieces left over that were rapidly chilled then refrigerated in the vacuum bag, how can I cook these so the chicken is moist and tender but definitely food safe? I'm probably just on the edge of them being pasteurised, but if these pieces are like the former they will be mottled with slight craters and small, isolated areas of pink meat - not the best presentation.

Comment: How big were the pieces & how long did you give it, in 'back to the boil plus *n* minutes'?

Comment: After Sous Vide I cut them into bite-size pieces and simmered them for 15 minutes. Asking for trouble I know, but I panicked and family wanted dinner !!!

Comment: That would have been overcooked even from raw. Everybody seems to fear that chicken will kill them & reacts by pre-emptively murdering it before it gets the chance ;)

Comment: Guilty as charged @Tetsujin.  Having suffered serious food poisoning as a child I would not wish it on my worst enemy, hence my assertion that food thermometers are the greatest gift to the home cook. If only I had the foresight to have used it last night !

Comment: Well… I've also had bad food poisoning on a couple of occasions, but never from anything **I've** cooked ;)) tbh, I get my timings from repetition until I can judge it. if I'm being exceptionally cautious, I'll specifically cut one slightly larger piece & test that as I'm ready to serve. If that one's done, so are the rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you cut finely enough - Chinese stir-fry style - you can cook it from raw in a hot sauce, in 'back to the boil plus 1 minute.'
For bite-sized chunks, that would be three minutes.

From cold but nearly cooked, I'd go with finely sliced & just bring back to the boil. Serve immediately. You might just be quick enough to not over-cook it.

Comment: Tried the latter option and that worked well.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. :)